# I want to show video from S3 to users in html <video> tag. Should I compress or stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to AWS and video streaming.

We have an app where you can upload video content. This video content should be uploaded full resolution, no compression, since it needs to be edited later by an editor. We also want to show the videos being uploaded to other users. For now I have a video tag with a signed url to the video on S3. Because some videos can be big, the video tag just shows a small black screen with only audio playing. Ofcourse if the user is on mobile it, they don't want to download these huge videos.

We use node.js with express.js to control the lambdas, which ofcourse give us the limitation of 60s before it dies. So video compression within the lambda is probably a no go?

Now my question is, what is the best practice? And what is the technology I should use? Is there a way to do video compression that is "free" or cheap? That way we can store a 720p, 480p, ... version of the video next to the full resolution to show to the user. Or should I implement streaming the video?

Thanks in advance for all the input! I'm here to learn.

Comment: You are looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/